# How to make relation between 2 tables in SQL with Sum and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

`1. players`

```
id,GameID,playerName,playerGroup
```

`2. scoretable`

id,playerID,playerScore

I'm trying to search the **top player** based on SUM of playerScore, in each group.
The result should be:
playername,playergroup,score

everything should be groupped by playergroup

```
SELECT players . * , SUM( st.playerScore ) AS playerScore, st.playerHole
FROM (SELECT * FROM players WHERE players.GameID = 7 GROUP BY players.playerName) players
LEFT JOIN scoretable st ON players.id = st.playerID
GROUP BY players.playerGroup
ORDER BY playerScore DESC
```

But the result is a wrong playerName.
Is possible to do that in other ways using a single query ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is not correct. Plz try this:-

```
SELECT players.id, players.GameID, players.playerName, players.playerGroup, SUM( st.playerScore ) AS playerScore, st.playerHole
FROM players JOIN scoretable st ON players.id = st.playerID
WHERE players.GameID = 7
GROUP BY players.id, players.GameID, players.playerName, players.playerGroup
ORDER BY playerScore DESC
```

Comment: ok, but the problem is that I can have more groups. In this case I cannot limit the result. The final result should be the best scored player of every group, in your example it shows only the best scored player

Answer (score 0):

This is LINQ version, you can convert to sql if you want.

```
var topPlayers = m_context.players
    .Join(m_context.scoretable, player=> player.Id, scoretable=> scoretable.PlayerId, 
    (player, scoretable) => new { 
                                PlayerName = player.PlayerName, 
                                PlayerGroup = player.PlayerGroup, 
                                Score = scoretable.PlayerScore, 
                                GameId = player.GameId })
    .Where(w => w.GameId == 7)
    .GroupBy(g => new {g.PlayerGroup, g.PlayerName, g.PlayerScore})
    .Select(s => new {
        PlayerName = s.Key.PlayerName,
        PlayerGroup = s.Key.PlayerGroup,
        TotalScore = s.Sum(score => score.PlayerScore)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.TotalScore)
    .Take(10).ToList(); //10 is top 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.GameID, p.playerName, p.playerGroup, SUM( st.playerScore ) AS playerScore, st.playerHole
FROM players p JOIN scoretable st ON players.id = st.playerID
WHERE players.GameID = 7
GROUP BY p.id, p.GameID, p.playerName, p.playerGroup
ORDER BY playerScore DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: LIMIT exactly display top player based on SUM of playerScore